# Scroll to bottom of the page when data added in body dynamically in react js?

Tags: reactjs

I have a component like below :

```
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }
    render() { 
        return (
            <div>
                {this.state.renderedThings.map((element, index) => (
                    <div key={index} className="cont">
                        <img alt="avatar" className="BlockOneImg" src={`./${element.image}.png`} role="presentation"/>
                    </div>
                )}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Images will be added dynamically every time, I need that scroll to current image added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have done the followings to make scroll to bottom or recently added DOM:

Add ref in your image div like below :

```
<div key={index} className="cont" ref={(ref) => this.newData = ref}        
   <img alt="avatar" className="BlockOneImg" src={`./${element.image}.png`}/>
</div>
```

and add a life cycle like below :

```
componentDidUpdate() {
    this.newData.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" })
}
```

Hope this works !

Comment: but what the use of componentDidUpdate() here ?

Comment: The componentDidUpdate is particularly useful when an operation needs to happen after the DOM is updated.

when you need something to be the absolutely last thing to be executed.
whenever your image is attaching to DOM, componentDidUpdate will do what you asked to do with DOM