# Cannot read property 'scrollIntoView' of undefined in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, scroll

I am trying to scroll div to button when page loaded and  added a new message in the list.

but here I am getting error 'scrollIntoView' undefined.

This is my code what I have tried so far

```
     componentDidUpdate() {
       this.scrollToBottom ()
      }

     componentDidMount() {
       this.scrollToBottom ()
      }

       scrollToBottom = () => {
      this.messagesEnd.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth",  });
     } 
  <div style={{ float:"left", clear: "both" }}
  ref={(el) => (this.messagesEnd = el)}>
  </div>
```

what Is wrong here why it is showing this error.

Your help would be highly appropriated

Comment: Where is  `that.messagesEnd` defined?

Comment: Welcome Kuldeed! 

Thanks for sharing your problem with us. We'd like to help you. Therefore we will need more information as well as a more specific problem description: 1) Could you copy-paste the exact error message? 2) Could you add more lines of code? 3) Your text is kind of hard to read. May I recapture it and send you a proposal how I have read your question?

Comment: @Dario Sorry it is `this' I have updated my question

Comment: @MichaelCzechowski Hi, Thanks for your reply, Actually here I want to scroll to bottom when component loaded and new item added in list, so after researching on internet I have came across with this method but facing issue `ScrollView undefined `

Comment: In order to get help you should provide your messagesend as well

Comment: @behzad  my problems is meets this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48617331/scroll-to-bottom-of-the-page-when-data-added-in-body-dynamically-in-react-js

Comment: @MichaelCzechowski, Hi, I have reproduced my problem here can you  have a look on it https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-rjamzk

Answer (score 4):

You can try to adjust `scrollToBottom()` method like:

```js
scrollToBottom = () => 
      this.messagesEnd && this.messagesEnd.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth",  });
```

Answer (score 1):

I got solution of my problem.
 HTML

```
 <div className="main-comment" ref={(elem) => this.container = elem}>
    //Your another div or content goes here
      </div>
```

in.ts page code

```
componentDidMount(){
this. scrollToBottom()
}
 componentDidUpdate(){
    this.scrollToBottom()
    }


 scrollToBottom = () => {
      if(this.container){
      this.container.scrollTop = this.container.scrollHeight
       }
```