# How to scroll to bottom of div

Tags: reactjs

I have troubles with scrolling down my component. I want scroll bar thumb to be at the very end of chat div from the start. I am not sure what the probleme is here. MessageTo and MessageFrom are components that represent paragraphs with text and display author's name. ChatInput is textarea with send button.

```
import React from 'react';
import './index.css';
import MessageFrom from './message-from';
import MessageTo from './message-to';
import ChatInput from './chat-input';
import SimpleBarReact from 'simplebar-react';
import 'simplebar/src/simplebar.css';


class Chat extends React.Component {

    
    componentDidMount() {
        
        this.scrollToBottom();
    }
    componentDidUpdate(){
        this.scrollToBottom()
    }
    scrollToBottom = () => {
        this.el.scrollIntoView({behavior:"smooth"});
    }

    render(){
        
        return(
            <div className="chat" id="slider-container">
                <SimpleBarReact style={{maxHeight: 680}} id="scroll-bar-cont">
                    <div className="messages-container" id="for-slider" >
                        <MessageFrom />
                        <MessageTo />
                        <div style={{ float:"left", clear: "both" }}
                        ref={el => {this.el=el;}}>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </SimpleBarReact>   
                <ChatInput />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Chat;
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/great-currying-x4m8m?file=/src/message-to.js
It works well. But It doesn't work in next level component.

Comment: this.el.current.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' }) ?

Comment: If I place this.el.current.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' }) instead of this.el.scrollIntoView({behavior:"smooth"}) then I get TypeError: Cannot read property 'scrollIntoView' of undefined. I already tried that option

Comment: @ОлегВойтинський That is the current syntax, OP is using legacy syntax for react refs.

Comment: Is `Chat` actually receiving updated props to trigger an update rerender? Does the div scroll into view on the initial mount/render?

Comment: @NixoN maybe this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58113575/cannot-read-property-scrollintoview-of-undefined-in-reactjs
will help.
Try the first and the second solution.

Comment: @DrewReese Currently, no. It doesn't scroll into view on the initial mount

Comment: Can you create a simple codesandbox that reproduces the scrolling issue that we may live debug?

Comment: Yes. One moment

Comment: Actually the problem was with SimpleBarReact component. Now everything is alright

Comment: Yes, many times issues become more apparent when you attempt to distill code down to simpler examples. Kudos, mate.